# what are some good apps for backing up all iphone data to dropbox?

Tags: iphone, backup, dropbox

I'm already using the Dropbox iPhone app, but it only backs up my photos.

Basically, I'm looking for the iPhone equivalent of the Android "SanDisk Memory Zone" app, which automatically and regularly backups my contacts, docs, files, etc to my Dropbox account. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sandisk.mz&hl=en Preferably, a solution for a non-jailbroken phone.

Can anyone recommend an app that will backup other data to my Dropbox account?

Comment: Keep in mind, because of the security of iOS, I would be surprised if you find anything that automatically backs up every so often. You will likely have to at least open the app to get it to perform a backup.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the sandboxing applied to all application in iOS it is not possible to backup "everything" to Dropbox. Dropbox access must be enabled by the individual application (as a lot of text editors etc. do) or be based on public APIs (like for Photos).

If you are just looking for a way to easily backup everything, iCloud backup would be an option. But you'll need an iPhone to recover any data from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does PhoneView do what you need?  http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Comment: Afraid not.  I have an unlimited data plan;  want something that will backup to my Dropbox (or other cloud) drive regularly/immediately.  No manual docking or syncing with my home computer required.